# LocalStrategy of passportjs is not being called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm trying to build a login system using [passportJS](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport). For some reason, LocalStrategy  is not being called from passport.authenticate(). No idea why. Database is mongodb. I have a collection for users in db. Can anyone help me regarding this issue? Thanks. Here is the code:

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mysql = require('mysql');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/WelcomeLimoUsa');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Init App
var app = express();

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));


// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Variables
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.use('/admin', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

**login.html**

```
<form action="/users/admin" method="post" class="well form-horizontal">
        <p>
            <strong>Admin User Name: </strong>
            <input type="text" name="username" size="25" class="form-control" placeholder="User Name">
        <p>
        <p>
            <strong align="center">Admin Password: </strong> 
            <input align="center" type="password" size="15" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password">
        <p>
        <p>
            <input align="center" type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-success" style="font-weight:600"> 
            <input align="center" type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-default" style="font-weight:600">
    </form>
```

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

var router = express.Router();

// Login
router.get('/admin', function(req, res){
    res.render('./login.html');
});

router.get('/error', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile("./loginerror.html");
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
   User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
    });
   });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/admin', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/admin',
                                   failureRedirect: '/users/error',
                                   failureFlash: true }), function(req,res){
  var user_name = req.body.userid;
  var password=req.body.password;
  console.log("User name = " + user_name + ", password is "+ password);

  res.redirect('/admin');
});



module.exports = router;
```

**user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// User Schema
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    var query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
        if(err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't see `passport.initialize()` at first . So, any errors in the console? what happens when you submit the form?

Comment: No error in the console.Data goes through when form is submitted but it seems it's failing in LocalStrategy call since failureRedirect is called.

Comment: Does it get to `function(username, password, done)`?